# Debug two Azure roles at the same time

Tags: debugging, azure, azure-web-roles, azure-worker-roles

I am trying to connect a WorkerRole to a WebRole in Azure using Internal Endpoints.

But how do you debug this? If I start one of the roles from my solution, I (obviously) can't start debug other project, since you can't debug two projects at once.

If I fire up another instance of Visual Studio, I can start the other role from there, and it loads into the Compute Emulator. However, when I try to get to one of the roles from the other (using RoleEnvironment.Roles["RoleName"]), only the current role is present in that collection.

So how do you go about debugging inter-role communication? Is there an object superseding RoleEnvironment that should be used for inter-role communication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can definitely run and debug two projects in a solution at the same time.  In Visual Studio, view the Solution properties, and in Common Properties >> Startup Project, select multiple projects and specify the projects you want to start.

[image: Multiple Projects]